# Swagger UI Authentication Header

Tags: jwt, swagger, swagger-ui, api-key

Currently I have a process that a user can go through to get a JSON Web Token (JWT).  This JWT is then used to set the `X-Access-Token` header for all http requests to the API.  I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I believe it is possible to add to `api_definition.yaml` so that a field comes up where the user can enter their JWT, and this can then be added as a header to all the calls.

---

## Solution Attempts

I added the following to `api_definition.yaml`

```
securityDefinitions:
  UserSecurity:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-Access-Token

security: [ { jwt: [] } ]
```

This doesn't seem to change anything in the Swagger-UI and I'm not entirely sure how to make it so that the user can input their key?

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI - 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Helen swagger v 2.0

Comment: @Helen I was mistaken. I'm using Swagger 2.0 and Swagger UI 3.0.3

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669302/swagger-and-jwt-token-authentication/47725647#47725647

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The security scheme name in the `security` key must match the name used in `securityDefinitions`:

```
securityDefinitions:
  UserSecurity:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-Access-Token

security:
  - UserSecurity: []
```

Then you should see the **Authorize** button in the Swagger UI header.

Comment: It looks like the Authorize button is still not showing up

Comment: I also had to add: 

schemes: - http